# pass two function references to a constructor occurs error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor, javascript-objects

I wanna create instance of object in javascript. I try to pass two function references to another class's constructor. But it throws error like below:

> *this.onFailFunction is not a function*

But, If I pass just one reference (onSuccess) it works. What is difference?

**index.html**

```
<script>

            function onSuccess(data, message)
            {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(message);
            }


            function onFail(data, message, errorCode)
            {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(message);
                console.log(errorCode);
            }
            var callBack = new EbookCallBack(onSuccess, onFail);
            callBack.mainCallback.callSuccessFunction({success:false, message:"Wovvv", errorcode:1, data:"asdsa"});

        </script>
```

**ebookcallback.js**

```
class EbookCallBack 
{

    constructor(onSuccessFunction, onFailFunction) 
    {
        this.onSuccessFunction = onSuccessFunction;
        this.onFailFunction = onFailFunction;
        this.mainCallback = new CallBack(this.onSuccess, this.onError);
    }

    onSuccess(result) 
     {
        if(result.success)
        {
            this.onSuccessFunction(result.data, result.message);
        }
        else
        {
            this.onFailFunction(result.data, result.message, result.errorcode);
        }
    }

    onError(message) 
    {
        if(this.onErrorFunction !== undefined) 
        {
            this.onErrorFunction(message);
        } 
    }


}
```

**maincallback.js**

```
class CallBack 
{

    constructor(onSuccessFunction, onErrorFunction) 
    {
        this.onSuccessFunction = onSuccessFunction;
        this.onErrorFunction = onErrorFunction;
    }

    callSuccessFunction(data) 
    {
        this.onSuccessFunction(data);
    }

    callErrorFunction(message) 
    {
        this.onErrorFunction(message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem starts at this part:

```
this.mainCallback = new CallBack(this.onSuccess, this.onError);
```

Because it will pass the function `this.onSuccess` and `this.onError` (which isn't defined anyway) without any *connection* to the `EbookCallBack` object, so later the `this` in this functions refers to the global object and not to the `EbookCallBack` anymore.

So if `callSuccessFunction` is called on `CallBack`, and this function will call `this.onSuccessFunction(data)`, which then calls the `onSuccess` function you originally passed from the `EbookCallBack`, but this function will be called in the context of the global object and not in the one of the `EbookCallBack`.

You would need to use `bind`.

```
this.mainCallback = new CallBack(this.onSuccess.bind(this), this.onError.bind(this) );
```

(`this.onError.bind(this)` would right now fail, because `onError` is not defined)

Answer (score 1):

"this" is being lost. Inside EbookCallback,

```
onSuccess(result) 
 {
    if(result.success)
    {
        this.onSuccessFunction(result.data, result.message);
    }
    else
    {
        this.onFailFunction(result.data, result.message, result.errorcode);
    }
}
```

I set up a breakpoint in chrome devtools and when you get to `this.onFailFunction`, "this" is of the CallBack class, not the EbookCallback class. That's because when you call `this.onSuccessFunction(data);`, the context is set to the CallBack object

You can fix "this" by replacing `new CallBack(this.onSuccess, this.onError);` with `new CallBack(this.onSuccess.bind(this), this.onFailFunction.bind(this));`

---

## EDIT

It occurs to me that nobody provided a potential alternative to 'bind'

`this.mainCallback = new CallBack(this.onSuccess, this.onError);` could be changed to the following:

```
this.mainCallback = new CallBack(function(result){
    this.onSuccess(result);
}, function(message){
    this.onError(message);
});
```

This solution might be more intuitive for some.

Comment: Yes. EbookCallBack class is between index.html page's script and Callback class. I access reference of CallBack class by EbookCallBack class

Comment: @t.niese answered the question first. So, I accept his answer. Thank you too.

Comment: @hkaraoglu i editted my answer to provide an alternative solution

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a binding problem. When you do this:

```
callErrorFunction(message) 
{
   this.onErrorFunction(message);
}
```

...you're calling the function in the `EbookCallBack` class, but your `this` variable is bound to the current object (`Callback`), even when you're executing code in a different class.

Basically, using `this` in javascript is extremely difficult and confusing. I generally recommend not doing it at all if you can help it. Lots of programmers try to write javascript as if it's Java and wrap everything inside objects, but you really don't need to do that at all! (Are you by any chance a Java coder in a previous life?)

An OOP style in javascript adds a lot of boilerplate and bugs with `this`. You may find a functional style a lot more readable and maintainable. Check this out:

```
//just a plain JS object, not a class
var myCallbacks = {
    onSuccess: function( data, message ) {
       //do something
    },
    onFail: function( data, message, errorCode ) {
       //do something else
    }
};

tryTheThing( "fish", myCallbacks );

function tryTheThing( data, myCallbacks ) {
   if ( data === "fish" ) {
      myCallbacks.onSuccess(data, "Yay");
   } else {
      myCallbacks.onFail(data, "boo", 51);
   }
}
```

Much simpler, right? No need for classes or `this`. Or even better, use Javascript Promises, which already encapsulate this behaviour:

```
tryTheThing( "fish" )
   .then( function( data, message ) {
      //success
   }).catch( function( data, message, errorcode ) {
      //fail
   });

function tryTheThing( data ) {
   return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) { 
      if ( data === "fish" ) {
         resolve( data, "yay" );
      } else {
         reject( data, "boo", 51 );
      }
   });
}
```

Promises are a core part of javascript now and a great way to handle callbacks without polluting your function parameters!